# Inferring nested Typescript generics

Tags: typescript

Give the following Typescript definitions:

```
type FooBar = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

type PickedFoo = Pick<FooBar, "foo">;
// type PickedFoo = {
//   foo: string;
// }

type Remaining<Picked extends Pick<T, any>, T> = Omit<T, keyof Picked>;

type RemainingBar = Remaining<PickedFoo, FooBar>;
// type RemainingBar = {
//   bar: string;
// }
```

Is there a way to rewrite `Remaining` to only take a single generic argument and automatically infer the omitted keys? For example:

```
type RemainingBar = Remaining<PickedFoo>;
// type RemainingBar = {
//   bar: string;
// }
```

Comment: You don't need your `Remaining` type in the above, just `type RemainingBar = Omit<FooBar, "foo">;` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGYkMN). But I don't think you can get back to `FooBar` (and thus to `RemainingBar`) from `PickedFoo`, no. The information isn't there.

Comment: My guess is that's impossible, `PickedFoo` doesn't contain the source information (it only contains `foo`) so that `RemainingBar` doesn't have any clue where to get the `bar` from.

Comment: Given that this is impossible, what should we do with the question?  Should one of the previous commenters just write up an answer saying as much?